# How much do type of line endings have to do with determining the determined file encoding in vim or Notepad++?

Tags: vim, character-encoding, notepad++

Opening a file in `vim` or Notepad++ allows you to see a guess as to what file encoding a file 
 might have.

I have a file that I recently used vim under Linux to replace the line endings with `\r` and then later determined that I needed to know what type of encoding it was in.

I attempted to determine the encoding of the file using VIM (for Linux) and Notepad++ (for windows).

`vim` determines it to be `fileencoding=latin1` and Notepad++ determines it to be `ANSI`

Do line endings have anything to do with determining the encoding?  Would the fact that I changed the line endings have an effect on the detected character encoding?

Comment: This suggests that they are the same: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc195054.aspx

Comment: Oh so Latin-1 and ANSI are the same thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absent a *byte order mark* (BOM) at the beginning of the text file, the editor has to apply some heuristics to determine the file encoding. In Vim, this is controlled by the `'fileencodings'` setting.

It is unlikely that the file's line endings (CR vs. CR-LF) influence the heuristics. Rather, the encoding names are not standardized, so different editors and tools come up with their own names.

You can find out about Vim's naming scheme via `:help encoding-values`. Presumably, the `latin1` corresponds to what is called `ANSI` in Notepad++, and is frequently referred to as ISO 8859-1.